# Trying to get right click in Fltk GUI in c++

Tags: c++, button, callback, fltk

I have a Fl_Button in my program that is linked to a call back method. I am trying to check if it is a right click button or a left click button.

This is where I make my buttons and set their callbacks.

```
int x = 50;
int y = 25;
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {

        this->grid[i][j] = new Fl_Button(x +i*60, y +j*60, 60, 60, "" );
        this->grid[i][j]->callback(cbGiveValue, this);

    }
}
```

In the call back now I want to do different directions when its a right click vs a left click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this by calling Fl::event_button() inside the callback function.
LMB=1, RMB=3, as far as I remember.

NOTE: the callback can be triggered manually as well, in which case I have no idea what will be the return value.